# Error: One or more models did not validate, Add a related_name argument to the definition

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm gettings this error when running "manage.py validate" in my application.

Error: One or more models did not validate:
ipn.paypalipn: Accessor for field 'custom' clashes with related field 
'Actor.paypalipn_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 
'custom'.
dashboard.paypalipn: Accessor for field 'custom' clashes with related field 
'Actor.paypalipn_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 
'custom'.

This is in an other model.py i got under Dashboard/ models.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):

ipn_obj = sender

actor_id = ipn_obj.custom

if actor_id == "Upgrade all users!":
    User.objects.update(paid=True)

if ipn_obj.payment_status == "Completed":

    from actors.models import Actor
    from commerce.models import Transaction

    actor = Actor.objects.get(id=actor_id)

    accountdetails = actor.account_set.latest('pk')

    signupbonus = 0


    transaction = Transaction()
    transaction.actor = actor
    transaction.amount = ipn_obj.mc_gross
    transaction.currency = ipn_obj.mc_currency
    transaction.transaction_flag = 'paid'
    transaction.transaction_type = 'deposit'
    transaction.payment_method = 'Paypal'
    transaction.payment_reference = ipn_obj.txn_id
    transaction.payment_message = 'OK'
    transaction.transaction_date = timezone.now()
    transaction.UserIp = actor_ip()
    transaction.save()           

    currentamount = accountdetails.balance
    accountdetails.balance = float(signupbonus) + float(currentamount) + float(ipn_obj.mc_gross)
    accountdetails.save()

payment_was_successful.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

Here's in models.py, Actor

```
class Actor(User):

def create_actor_number():
    try:
        return int(Actor.objects.order_by('-id')[0].actor_key) + 1
    except:
        return 5001

ssn = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='', blank=True, help_text="Social security number")
address = models.OneToOneField(ActorAddress, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Actor full address information")
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='', blank=True, help_text="Actor main phone number (Format: + and country-code eg +4670323435)")
alt_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='', blank=True, help_text="Actor alternative phone number")
alt_email = models.EmailField(default='', blank=True, help_text="Actor alternative email")
skype = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='', blank=True, help_text="Actor Skype ID")
twitter = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='', blank=True, help_text="Actor Twitter account")
website = models.URLField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, help_text="Actor Website URL")
blog = models.URLField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, help_text="Actor Blog URL")   
linkedin_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='', blank=True, help_text="Actor LinkedIn account name") 
linkedin_ref = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='', blank=True, help_text="Actor LinkedIn reference number")
description = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text="More information about Actor")
company = models.ForeignKey(ActorCompany, null=True, blank=True)  
language = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=LANGUAGES, default='', blank=True, help_text="Stored as ISO codes (Sv, En, etc) in the DB")
timezone = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='UTC+01:00', blank=True, help_text="UTC TimeZone <a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone' target='_blank'>(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)</a>, eg UTC+01:00 for London")
invite_code = models.CharField(max_length=16, default='', blank=True, help_text="invite code")
updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True, help_text="Auto generated by system")
lockout_times = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='', blank=True, help_text="lockout times")
actor_key = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=create_actor_number, help_text="Actor unique key key used for identification")
secret_key = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=make_uuid, help_text="Actor unique secret key used to identify the Actor in API calls")
access_key = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=make_uuid, help_text="Actor unique access key used to identify the Actor in API calls")
confirmation_key = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=make_uuid, help_text="Registered user validate email")
email_confirmation = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="To Check if User validated email")
type = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='', blank=True, help_text="NOT IN USE")
category = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='', blank=True, help_text="NOT IN USE")
partner_status = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False, help_text="Describe whether the actor is partner of. If Actor is partner, True will be stored. False is the default value.")
partner_commission = models.FloatField(default=0.0, help_text="Commission percentage allocated to partner")  
partner = models.ForeignKey('actors.Actor', related_name='partner_from', limit_choices_to={"partner_status": "true"}, null=True, blank=True, help_text="This actor is connected to partner.")
#To Check if User Logged in for the first time
is_first = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text="To Check if user logged in for the first time.")
signup_method = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='', blank=True, help_text="Determine how the user is registered in")
pkb_email = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Send partner kickback email', help_text="To check e-mail should be sent to partner")
email_subscribed = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text="Subscribe to notice e-mail")
sales_email = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text="To check e-mail should be sent to seller")
is_sellerregistered = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="To check if user registered for seller account.")
Login_IPnumber = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True, help_text="stores user ip when log in.")
Registration_IPnumber = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True, help_text="stores user ip when registration.")
google_client_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True, help_text="Google client ID.")
seller_commission = models.FloatField(default=-1.0, help_text="Seller commission percentage. Standard 50, 40, 30 or -1 for 0 commission")
currency = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=settings.BASE_CURRENCY, help_text="Actor's currency in ISO format")
objects = ActorManager()
```

Comment: post your models.py file

Comment: i've edited my question, you can see

Answer (score 0):

i think your project has two models.py file one of them under dashboard directory the other one is under ipn directory.

In these two models.py you have model named "Paypalipn" and these two models have field named "custom" with related "Actor" model.

So when Django try to make reverse relation from "Actor" model both of them are same "Actor.paypalipn_set"

So you need to add "related_name" argument to the definition in two models(dasboard/paypalipn and ipn/paypalipn) for 'custom' field

Comment: ahh okey, i see now that i hade multiplie classes with the same name. I just removed one that i didn't use. Thx for help